# is FreeLibrary() working on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm looking inside somebody's code (perhaps yours :D ) where there is a function called `FreeLibrary()`.

I would like to know if this function works for linux too. Actually, I tried to googled it but got only some pages related to Windows OS.

if this function is not for linux, what is the equivalent function for linux ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your "update". That code shouldn't compile at all. I would expect g++ to complain, first of all, about closeDL() being redefined, even if g++ didn't complain about unknown symbol "HMODULE".

Comment: hmmm... actualy I understand I didn't see the balises `#ifdef _win32` so nevermind, I will delete my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of FreeLibrary() that comes from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The equivalent function in Linux is dlclose():

http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/dlopen.3.html

Answer (score 1):

The *FreeLibrary* Windows functions [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> Frees the loaded dynamic-link library (DLL) module and, if necessary, decrements its reference count. When the reference count reaches zero, the module is unloaded from the address space of the calling process and the handle is no longer valid.

The Linux *dlclose* [function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose) is very similar

> The function dlclose() decrements the reference count on the dynamic library handle handle. If the reference count drops to zero and no other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is unloaded.

Many examples on the Net on how to use Linux dynamic libraries, for instance [this one](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

Comment: I just read the whole page (last url). It was very instructive. You deserve +1